# Add a "named" path to .bashrc

Tags: 12.10, bashrc, paths

I have an error of

```
[error] Android SDK not found. You might need to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT or ANDROID_HOME
```

I have Android SDK installed and, obviously, I have to add a line in .bashrc file saying where location of Android SDK is. So I can do this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me123/android-sdk-linux/sdk
```

But would it be treated as `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` or `ANDROID_HOME`? And how do I add a "named" path to .bashrc?

Answer (score 1):

Use export and define it like any other variable. In your example:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/me123/android-sdk-linux/sdk
```

You can also just add it to your path instead of exporting.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/me123/android-sdk-linux/sdk
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME
```